# Как переделать табличную верстку в блочную?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вот исходник

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2></th>
      <th>3></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2.1</th>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3.1</th>
      <td>3.2</td>
      <td>3.4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Вам уже ответили, но я бы порекомендовал еще почитать этот [урок](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/) по позиционированию контента, если интересно.

Comment: спасибо большое, полезный урок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.head,
.body {
  width: 140px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='head'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class='body'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class='body'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: отметьте ответ, если не сложно)

Comment: с удовольствием, но 15 балов для этого нужно :\

Comment: @Atomrr для галочки -- не нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Делается при помощи `display: table | table-row | table-cell`
`table` - таблица
`table-row` - рядок
`table-cell` - ячейка

```css
div {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted white;
}

.table {
    display: table;

    background: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #3a87ad;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    background: #f2dede;
    border-color: #b94a48;
}

.cell {
    background: #fbeed5;
    border-color: #c09853;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">1</div>
                <div class="cell">2</div>
                <div class="cell">3</div>
            </div>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">2.1</div>
                <div class="cell">2.2</div>
                <div class="cell">2.3</div>
            </div>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">3.1</div>
                <div class="cell">3.2</div>
                <div class="cell">3.3</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно без свойств display: table-cell, row?

Comment: А чем они плохи?

Comment: вот страница, где это нужно применить http://front.ksi-finance.com/. Блок Курсы ЦБ. Я бы сделал через эти св-ва, но люди стоящие выше сказали, что нужна блочная верстка